# Entering Password in su- through loop

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, root, brute-force

The Scenario is like I have a list of root passwords.
But i don't want to keep trying  Manually.
So i wrote the shell script :

> for i in {1..26}
>
> do
>
> su - >>result
>
> done

and all my password are on a file **"attempt.txt".**

Now on Command Prompt i type the Command :

> **bash p2.sh < attempt.txt**

But It shows errors : "**Standard in must be a tty"**

So is there some way I can enter these passwords through some codes or commands without manually typing each Of those?
Please tell a command-line approach instead of some advanced utility software. I'm in it for learning.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
 while read my_pass
 do 
        echo $my_pass | sudo -S command
 done < file_name
```

Three comments: you cannot use *su* inside a script file, you will need to use *sudo* with the  *-S* option which, according to the man,

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.

Second, if you do not like to write the file_name inside the script, use one of the $n arguments, like $1 if it is the only parameter passed.

Third, are you sure collecting all of your passwords in a single, unencrypted file is such a good idea?

Comment: No definately it's not a good idea. But In my College Campus Lab there are computers with different passwords, and we are told not to change them. Well since there are 12-14 different password, I dont want to try manually one after the other. So I want that I can test the working one using a script.
Ideally they should not keep a password or just give us a list of computer no. and its respective password, but they don't.

Comment: Hope this works, I will test it during my lab tomorrow :)

Comment: Wasn't able totry it today, But I feel It will work. Thanks :)